# How do I add missing architecture to linked framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, frameworks, spotify

I'm trying to add Spotify SDK to my project by adding `SpotifyiOS.framework` from https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk as a dependency, but I end up with the following error

"The linked framework 'SpotifyiOS.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64."

[image: Error Image]

When I change `SpotifyiOS.framework` from "Do Not Embed" to "Embedded & Sign" or "Embed without Signing" I get a different error

"/Users/matthewchukwuemeka/Work/sporti/sporti.xcodeproj Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'SpotifyiOS.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator."

[image]

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue, any suggestion will go a long way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a GitHub issue on the Spotify iOS SDK that should solve it

https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/325#issuecomment-916860367

> Remove 'SpotifyiOS.framework' and add 'SpotifyiOS.xcframework' and make sure to check Embed & Sign. It should work